# package broken, and no installation accepted by terminal

Tags: 13.10

I installed cinnamon and then was trying to install other apps but as you can see on the picture, package brocken, any ideas how could this error be solved?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> **Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them,
>   since they are a common source of problems.**

To check if you are using third party repositories, go to **System Settings** → **Software & Updates** and select **Other Software** tab, and if you are really using third party repositories, disabe them:

[image: Ubuntu - Other Software]

> **Futhermore run the following command in a terminal: apt-get install -f**

To do so, open your [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) and run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

More about: [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Comment: Hi I still have the same problem 
the command above doesnot remove the independent

Comment: Which command?!? The purpose of `sudo apt-get install -f` is to correct a system with broken dependencies. If you want to remove "Independent" sources, the simpliest way is to remove them as in the image. Nothing more then simple.